# Key Error in Python with for loop and list comprehension

Tags: python, keyerror

Getting a key error 197 when I am writing this code. However when I am debugging by removing the for loop and considering values instead of i, it is working.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Customer Type': ['physician/doctor/gp', 'private hospital', 'private hospital', 'private hospital', 'pharmacy-retail'],
     'Invoice Date Month J&J': ['Oct', 'May', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'May'], 
     'Invoice Date Year J&J': [2015.0, 2016.0, 2016.0, 2017.0, 2018.0], 
     'Matching Type': ['Credit/Other', 'Credit/Other', 'Credit/Other', 'Credit/Other', 'Credit/Other']}

df_CT = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

hosp = ['hospital', 'hosp', 'hosps','hospitals', 'hsp','clinics',
        'clinic','clin',"hosp'tl", 'health', 'doctor', 'pract', 'clinical','patients',
       'hlthcare','nurse', 'clncal', 'cln', 'doctors', 'clin','hlth', 'nursing']

for i in range(df_CT.shape[0]):
    if (any(j in df_CT.loc[i,'Customer Type'] for j in hosp)):
        df_CT.loc[i,'CustomerType_Level0'] = 'Hospitals'
```

Error as follows:
[Key Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w1wW.png)

Comment: you should provide a minimal, reproducible code, we don't know what `df_CT` is (if it is a DataFrame, you probably shouldn't be using a loop)

Comment: @mozway yes it is a dataframe. what should i use then?

Comment: you need to provide a complete minimal reproducible example (input DataFrame constructor, description of the logic, explicit expected output)

Comment: From code provided. I am unable to reproduce any error. It's running without any error and returning dataframe as output.

Answer (score 0):

How I see, you try to add new column in existing DataFrame, try it by insert method.

IE

```
df_CT.insert(loc=1, column='CustomerType_Level0', value=[])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry for creating new answers, but I cant comment until reach 50rep. Your problem is CustomerType_Level0 does not exist, you should add that column first, it can be nullable and then you shot easy to imput values by .loc

Comment: that's not the prob actually. it does exist - i have not shown it above. i want to modify the code within for loop that's where the key error is coming

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).